# Merging MS Access Rows - Using Advanced Logic

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, vba

For a couple of weeks now, I have been working on migrating my client from using Corel Paradox to Microsoft Access since Paradox has been long dead and it finally became unusable in a practical matter for my client.

As most of my development however is in server side work, my knowledge of VBA and TSQL is fairly basic which is why I'm having a bit of trouble grasping the logic required for the following task:

As part of the routine scripts run for database maintenance and updates (of customer info such as courses attended, date created, date of the last record change, address, etc.)  all customers are given a "date created" to mark when they first became clients, and a "date updated" which is simply the date of any changes to the customer file.

Now, the sticking point on my end is that in the database tables we have eight fields (with date fields also) for types of courses attended by the customer.

When we were using Paradox, we had a script which would compare the master database against our quarterly data set, and where duplicates were found the script would take the courses and push them back one and insert the latest course data.

Additionally the script would take the record which was most recent and update any personal information where changed.

While I've gotten most of the scripts done,  I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to recreate that feature of pushing back older dates to make room for the new records.

I have a feeling this is something which can be done with arrays, however after reading up on tSQL and VBA, I'm not sure which tool is right for the job.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: You really do not want arrays if you can sensibly avoid them. I suggest you post some sample data and outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer but an attempt to understand what you are trying to do.

The key phrase seems to be "I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to recreate that feature of pushing back older dates to make room for the new records."

Does this sentence mean you have a customer record like this:

```
|  Oldest  |           |           |           |           |           |   Newest  |
Course|Date|Course|Date|Course|Date|Course|Date|Course|Date|Course|Date|Course|Date|
```

Then when the the customer attends a new course, you discard the oldest Course/Date, move the others left one slot and insert the new Course/Date at the end.

Please, please tell me I have misunderstood!  This is the sort of trick we got up to before the days of relational databases.  What if the customer attends more than eight courses in a quarter?  We've let the DBMS handle these complications for the last 30 years.

You should have a Course Attended table, linked to the customer, with attributes Course and Date.  All you have to do is add a new record for each new attendance.  If you want a routine that deletes the older Attendance records from the Course Attended table then write one.  If they want a routine that displays the 8 most recent attendances, write an SQL query to get them.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you so much! You literally hit the nail on the head and thank you very much for mentioning the fact this type of system isn't  what is used today because as MS DOS was what I uesd as a child rather than a professional trying to bridge these concepts has been difficult. To be more precise about the table - we actually only have eight fields mainly because that's the max for the program. I'll look into your solution shortly although I also have I ton of legacy tables which I'll need to address also.

Comment: Bringing forward old systems can be both fascinating and frustrating.  I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your info is a huge help.